# Incremental data transfer using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

In an on-premises SQL Server database, I have a number of tables in to which various sales data for a chain of stores is inserted during the day. I would like to "harvest" these data to Azure every, say 15, minutes via Data Factory and an on-premises data management gateway. Clearly, I am not interested in copying *all* table data every 15 minutes, but only in copying the rows that have been inserted since last fetch.
As far as I can see, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#data-dependency-and-validation) suggests using data "slices" for this purpose. However, as far as I can see, these slices require a timestamp (e.g. a datetime) column to exist on the tables where data is fetched from.

1. Can I perform a "delta" fetch (i.e. only fetch the rows inserted since last fetch) without having such a timestamp column? Could I use a sequential integer column instead? Or even have no incrementally increasing column at all?
2. Assume that the last slice fetched had a window from 08:15 to 08:30. Now, if the clock on the database server is a bit behind the Azure clock, it might add some rows with the timestamp being set to 08:29 *after* that slice was fetched, and these rows will not be included when the next slice (08:30 to 08:45) is fetched. Is there a smart way to avoid this problem? Shifting the slice window a few minutes into the past could minimize the risk, but not totally eliminate it.

Comment: To counter clock differences, you can set an 'delay' on the policy object of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Take Azure Data Factory out of the equation.  How do you arrange for transfer of deltas to a target system?  I think you have a few options:

1. add date created / changed columns to the source tables.  Write parameterised queries to pick up only new or modified values.  ADF supports this scenario with time slices and [system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-functions-variables).  Re identity column, you could do that with a stored procedure (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742505/azure-data-factory-and-stored-procedure)) and a table tracking the last ID sent.
2. Engage [Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx) (CDC) on the source system.  This will allow you to access deltas via the CDC functions.  Wrap them in a proc and call with the system variables, similar to the above example.
3. Always transfer all data, eg to staging tables on the target.  Use delta code `EXCEPT` and `MERGE` to work out what records have change; obviously not ideal for large volumes, this would work for small volumes.

HTH

Comment: This assumes you have the ability to alter the tables. Not all environments allow this

Comment: This is an old post - ADF v2 has moved on.  See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) for more info.  @clifton_h.

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to add this capability into ADF. It may start from sequential integer column instead of timestamp. Could you please let me know if the sequential integer column will help?

Comment: Yes, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By enabling "Change Tracking" on SQL Server, you can leverage on the "SYS_CHANGE_VERSION " to incrementally load data from On-premise SQL Server or Azure SQL Database via Azure Data Factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-tracking-feature-portal

Answer (score -1):

If using SQL Server 2016, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631669.aspx#Enabling-system-versioning-on-a-new-table-for-data-audit. Otherwise, you can implement the same using triggers.

And use NTP to synchronize your server time.